# Tar does not exclude

Tags: tar

I use

```
tar hczf t.tar.gz * --exclude="./test1"
```

where test1 is the name of a directory to exclude files from being tarred.

Unfortunately, tar still includes those directories. How can I have tar exclude directories?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` that specifics "all files in the current directory" should be the last item on your cmd-line

```
tar --exclude="./test1" hczf t.tar.gz * 
#--------------------------^-> tarFileName
#------------------------->f (for file)
```

This illustrates why the `--excl...` can't go inbetween `hczf t.tar.gz`.

The `f` option expects a filename right after it. So we have moved `--excl...` to the first option.

IHTH